# Built In Sort Behaviour Rich Faces 4.x

Tags: sorting, richfaces

We used Rich Faces 4.3.5 while migrating from Rich Faces 3 to 4. 
While using sorting in rich:dataTable , we needed to manually add sort behavior images (ascending and descending arrow images) since built in sorting has been removed in rich faces.

But as I see now in Rich Faces showcase 4.5.x latest version, sort images are getting displayed.

My question is : 
1)What version built in sort controls have been added in Rich Faces 4.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in sorting and filtering of the DataTable was added in RF 4.5.0.

Check [RichFaces 4.5.0.Final Release Announcement](http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2014/10/richfaces-450final-release-announcement.html).